# Modify .htaccess to make URL?variable=true change to URL/variable?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to change my .htaccess file so that if I go to:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?login=true`, it goes to `http://www.example.com/login`.

I currently have this code which removes index.php (which makes the above looks like `http://www.example.com/?login=true`).

```
RewriteEngine On
#remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
```

Comment: I'll definitely need other variants - basically anything that has ?something=something

Answer (score 0):

I would setup your rewrite rule the other way around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login$ /index.php?login=true
```

This way if a user browses to http://yourserver.com/login the actual page used is http://yourserver.com/index.php?login=true, but the first URL is shown in the browser. I assume this is what you are trying to achieve.

If you really need to do it in the direction you asked for, you can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^login=true$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /login [L,R=301]
```

This will fail of there are additional query parameters.

If you want to redirect http://yourserver.com/index.php to http://yourserver.com you can simply add the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: He probably needs that too or maybe he implemented all that in his PHP code already. I suspect what he wants is to not have broken links so if something links to one of those old pages he wants the pretty new link to show up.

Comment: How does that effect going to http://yourserver.com/index.php? I should have clarified, but if someone goes to http://yourserver.com/index.php, it should show just http://yourserver.com

Answer (score 0):

The following should work although there might something wrong with the line to exclude /system/*. Try testing with that commented out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^=]*)=true [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/system/.*
RewriteRule index.php /%1? [R=301,L]
```

The following page helped: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

This tester is cool but does have a few bugs in it: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the QUERY_STRING in a RewriteCond. I think this should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
#remove index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^=]*)=true [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule ^index\.php /%1? [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect anything which has index.php?=true to /action

Comment: `http://example.com/index.php?login=true` redirects to `http://example.com/login?login=true`, using your example.

Comment: True, you should add a ? to the redirect to replace the existing query string with an new empty one like Sarel Botha did. I edited the answer to include this. (And simplified the rule a bit).

Answer (score 0):

try  the following in the .htaccess in root directory of example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#rewrite http://www.example.com/anything to http://www.example.com/index.php?anything=true
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !system [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php?%1=true [L]


#301 redirect requests for example.com/index.php?anything=true to example.com/anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1? [L,R=301]
```